# the direction strength of corner-pin

Tags: shader, cg

i try to simulate the corner-pin effect in ae, and i use the inverse bilinear method(https://iquilezles.org/articles/ibilinear/) to do this, but i found the strength direction is different from the same in ae.

```
    // if edges are parallel, this is a linear equation
    if( abs(k2)<0.001 )
    {
        res = vec2( (h.x*k1+f.x*k0)/(e.x*k1-g.x*k0), -k0/k1 );
    }
    // otherwise, it's a quadratic
    else
    {
        float w = k1*k1 - 4.0*k0*k2;
        if( w<0.0 ) return vec2(-1.0);
        w = sqrt( w );

        float ik2 = 0.5/k2;
        float v = (-k1 - w)*ik2;
        float u = (h.x - f.x*v)/(e.x + g.x*v);
        
        if( u<0.0 || u>1.0 || v<0.0 || v>1.0 )
        {
           v = (-k1 + w)*ik2;
           u = (h.x - f.x*v)/(e.x + g.x*v);
        }
        res = vec2( u, v );
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

the first one is mine, and the other one is result in ae
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4zrm.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GptoT.png)

i want to get the same effect as that in ae, how to change the code or any other better ways to achieve that?